# Sorting some lines in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, sort, text-formatting

### 1. Summary

I don't understand, how I can sort lines in some places of file, not in all file.

It would be nice, if would be possible solve this task any gratis method.

---

### 2. Settings

#### 1. File structure

I have a big (19 MB) file `SashaMillionaire.md`, has questions of [**one game**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire%3F). It consists of repeating blocks. Each block has a 10 lines. Structure of file (using PCRE regular expressions)

```markdown
Millionaire
\d{18}
QUESTION.*
.*
.*
.*
.*
.*
.*
.*
Millionaire
\d{18}
QUESTION.*
.*
.*
.*
.*
.*
.*
.*
```

`SashaMillionaire.md` doesn't have another lines and text besides 10-lines blocks. It doesn't have blank lines and blocks with a greater or lesser number of lines than 10.

#### 2. Example content of file

```markdown
Millionaire
123456788763237476
QUESTION|2402394827049882049
Who is the greatest Goddess in the world?
Sasha
Kristina
Sasha
Katya
Valeria
AuthorOfQuestion
Millionaire
459385734954395394
QUESTION|9845495845948594999
Where Sasha live?
Novgorod
St. Petersburg
Kazan
Novgorod
Chistopol
Another author
Millionaire
903034225025025568
QUESTION|ABC121980850540445C
Another question.
Katya
Sasha
Kazan
Chistopol
Katya
Unknown author
```

---

### 3. Expected behavior

I need alphabetically sort lines 6—9, then sort 16—19, 26—29 and so on.

**but** no sort another lines.

[image: Example]

The result should be this:

```markdown
Millionaire
123456788763237476
QUESTION|2402394827049882049
Who is the greatest Goddess of the world?
Sasha
Katya
Kristina
Sasha
Valeria
AuthorOfQuestion
Millionaire
459385734954395394
QUESTION|9845495845948594999
Where Sasha live?
Novgorod
Chistopol
Kazan
Novgorod
St. Petersburg
Another author
Millionaire
903034225025025568
QUESTION|ABC121980850540445C
Another question.
Katya
Chistopol
Katya
Sasha
Kazan
Unknown author
```

---

### 4. Did not help

1. Googling
2. I find, that Unix commands `sort`, `sed` and `awk` can solve similar tasks, but I don't find, how I can solve my task use these commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each section starts with text `Millionaire`, you should be able to do this with `vim`/`ex` - either interactively, or scripted for example like so:

```
$ ex SashaMillionaire.md << 'EOF'
:g/^Millionaire$/+5,+8 sort
:1,$p
:q
EOF

Millionaire
123456788763237476
QUESTION|2402394827049882049
Who is the greatest Goddess in the world?
Саша
Валерия
Катя
Кристина
Саша
AuthorOfQuestion
Millionaire
459385734954395394
QUESTION|9845495845948594999
Where Sasha live?
Novgorod
Chistopol
Kazan
Novgorod
St. Petersburg
Another author
Millionaire
903034225025025568
QUESTION|ABC121980850540445C
Another question.
Katya
Chistopol
Katya
Kazan
Sasha
Unknown author
```

To modify the file in-place, replace print statement `1,$p` by `w`

```
ex SashaMillionaire.md << 'EOF'
:g/^Millionaire$/+5,+8 sort
:wq
EOF
```

or, if you prefer a one-liner instead of a heredoc,

```
printf ':g/^Millionaire$/+5,+8 sort\nwq\n' | ex SashaMillionaire.md
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! It works for English symbols. But I have a bugs, if I have Cyrillic symbols. [**Example file**](http://ix.io/y4S) — [**result**](http://ix.io/y4T). My file contains Cyrillic, Latin symbols and numbers. Thanks.

Comment: steeldriver, in your second variant (with `partsort.sh` file) [**output**](http://ix.io/y52) repeat for me 3 times... Thanks.

Comment: steeldriver: not for Cygwin... [**I don't find**](http://i.imgur.com/36qUNZB.png), how I can correct set it.

Comment: @СашаЧерных please see modified answer - the previous one was largely erroneous (it was doing the right thing - but on files saved from a previous run of the `split` command)

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`, you could do something like:

```
awk '
  $0 == "Millionaire" {
    if (n < 0) {
      close("sort")
      print last
    }
    n = 4
  }
  n > 0 {
    n--
    print
    next
  }
  n-- {print last | "sort"}
  {last = $0}
  END {
    if (n < 0) {
      close("sort")
      print last
    }
  }'
```

To sort the lines from the fourth after `Millionaire` to the second before the next `Millionaire`.