# How do I use sed and sort to grab text between two markers and sort them alphabetically?

Tags: text-processing, sed, sort

I would like to do the following:

1. Grab all text between two markers denoted in `someFile.txt`
2. Put text into an array that was split by `\n`
3. Sort array alphabetically
4. Replace text between two markers in `someFile.txt` with alphabetized version.

`someFile.txt` before manipulation:

```
// __MARKER__
../library/_shared/_shared/components/InfoPill/InfoPill.stories
../library/_shared/_shared/components/IconChevronRightBlack/IconChevronRightBlack.stories
../library/_shared/_shared/components/ButtonPrimary/ButtonPrimary.stories
// __MARKER__
```

`someFile.txt` after manipulation:

```
// __MARKER__
../library/_shared/_shared/components/ButtonPrimary/ButtonPrimary.stories
../library/_shared/_shared/components/IconChevronRightBlack/IconChevronRightBlack.stories
../library/_shared/_shared/components/InfoPill/InfoPill.stories
// __MARKER__
```

Comment: I don't see evidence of item #2, "put text into an arrow" ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I meant `array`, my bad.

Comment: is an array a requirement, or do you "just" need the lines between the markers to be sorted?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I would like the lines to be sorted. If I don't need to do step 2, then okay.

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`? there's a fairly straightforward way to do it using `ex/vi` as described here: [Sorting some lines in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373891/sorting-some-lines-in-a-file)

Comment: @steeldriver How do I put the information back into `someFile.txt` after using that command?

Comment: Change `:1,$p` (**p**rint) to `:1,$w` (**w**rite)

Comment: @steeldriver If I wanted to make it a one-liner, would this work? `printf ':g/__MARKER__/+1,/__MARKER__/-1 sort;:1,$w;:q' | ex someFile.txt`

Comment: You would need newlines rather than semicolons I think e.g. `printf ':g/__MARKER__/+1,/__MARKER__/-1 sort\n:1,$wq\n' | ex someFile.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `perl` is okay and file is small enough for memory requirements

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 'BEGIN{$m = "// __MARKER__\n"}
                  s|$m\K.*?(?=\n$m)|join "\n", sort split/\n/,$&|gse' ip.txt 
// __MARKER__
../library/_shared/_shared/components/ButtonPrimary/ButtonPrimary.stories
../library/_shared/_shared/components/IconChevronRightBlack/IconChevronRightBlack.stories
../library/_shared/_shared/components/InfoPill/InfoPill.stories
// __MARKER__
```

- `-0777` to slurp whole file as a string
- `$m = "// __MARKER__\n"` save the marker in a variable
- `$m\K.*?(?=\n$m)` capture the string between the markers
- `join "\n", sort split/\n/,$&` split the captured string on `\n`, then sort it and finally get a single string by joining the array elements
- `s` modifier to allow `.` to match `\n`
- `e` modifier to allow code in replacement section
- use `-i` option for inplace editing